# Does the Giant Rocktopus have a Swim Speed?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, published-adventures, movement, out-of-the-abyss

The Giant Rocktopus described in Out of the Abyss (p.28) is said to be a Giant Octopus that evolved to live on land.

It has a walking speed of 20 feet and a climbing speed of 10 feet.

Nothing is mentioned about a swim speed, though. Does this mean the Rocktopus has the Giant Octopus 60' swim speed, or did it lose its ability to swim entirely?

This matters a lot if a Druid tries to Wild Shape into the Giant Rocktopus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Nope

According to the official digital resource [dndbeyond.com](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-rocktopus), the Giant Rocktopus has a walking speed, climb speed, but no swim speed.

Comment: Is dndbeyond an official source?

Comment: @Merudo  Yup!  Sorry, should have clarified in my answer.

Comment: It is an official licensed source, but in this case they are manually creating a unique statblock for the rocktopus (as they do for all modified versions of existing statblocks in adventures, presumably related to their upcoming encounter builder), so it's possible they made a mistake in interpreting the adventure's description for it. I've asked them to confirm that it's correct with WotC.

Comment: @V2Blast I too am curious about how canonical the online material is.  As dndbeyond.com adds more features, I have a feeling it will figure more and more frequently into rpg.se answers.  But as you note, there might be reason to question the integrity of dndbeyond.com as a source of information.  Perhaps a topic of debate for a future meta post!